# UID of a message from POP3Folder is always null

Tags: java, email, jakarta-mail, pop3

I have coded a java program to get UID of a message from POP3folder in java. but the uid is always null.

Glimpse of my code is ,

```
String protocol="pop3";
Properties props = new Properties();
String SSL_FACTORY = "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory";
props.setProperty("mail.pop3.socketFactory.class",SSL_FACTORY);
props.setProperty("mail.pop3.socketFactory.fallback","false");
props.setProperty("mail.pop3.socketFactory.port",popPort);
props.setProperty("mail.pop3.port", popPort);
props.setProperty("mail.debug","true");

Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props,null);
store = session.getStore(protocol); 
store.connect(popServer,Integer.parseInt(popPort),userName,passwd);
folder = ((POP3Store)store).getFolder("INBOX");
folder.open(Folder.READ_WRITE);

Message[] msgs = folder.getMessages(1,1);
String uid = ((POP3Folder)folder).getUID(msgs[0]);
```

this uid is returned as null.

I have read the POP3Folder's getUID method and found that UIDL support is not available in the POP3Store, the code is

```
public synchronized String getUID(Message msg) throws MessagingException {
checkOpen();
POP3Message m = (POP3Message)msg;
try {
    if (!((POP3Store)store).supportsUidl)
return null;
```

}

In POP3Store supportsUidl is changed by the protocal's capabilities in getPort method,

```
p = new Protocol(host, portNum, session.getDebug(),
    session.getDebugOut(), session.getProperties(), "mail." + name,
    isSSL);
capabilities = p.getCapabilities();
supportsUidl = capabilities == null|| capabilities.containsKey("UIDL");
```

Please suggest me the solution for getting UID.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a POP3 server that support UIDs.  It appears that your POP3 server does not.  When you look at the [JavaMail debug output](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#debug), what capabilities does the server say it supports?

You can also [get rid of the socket factory settings, you don't need them](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#commonmistakes).

Comment: Following is the debug print I got, using javaxmail 1.5.7

DEBUG POP3: mail.pop3.disabletop: false
DEBUG POP3: mail.pop3.apop.enable: false
DEBUG POP3: mail.pop3.disablecapa: false
DEBUG POP3: connecting to host "pop.zoho.com", port 995, isSSL false
+OK POP3 mx.zohomail.com v1.0 server ready <2261649.1464184267298@mx.zohomail.com>
CAPA
+OK
USER
.
DEBUG POP3: server doesn't support TOP, disabling it
DEBUG POP3: authentication command trace suppressed
DEBUG POP3: authentication command succeeded

C: NOOP
S: +OK
UID is null

Comment: The formatting of the debug output is kind of messed up in your comment, it's better if you edit your question and add it there.  There is no JavaMail 1.5.7 so I don't know what version you're really using; recent versions include the version number in the debug output.  Also, the "C:" and "S:" debug output is from a very old version of JavaMail.  It should be on every line of the protocol output so I don't know what's going on there.  Still, from what I can see, it's pretty clear the server doesn't support UIDs, and there's nothing JavaMail can do about that.

Comment: You really should make sure you have a recent and consistent version of JavaMail.  You may be using a very old version.